How to read RSA private or public key from XML
I am not able to understand how to assign private key from a XML file into a c sharp variable.
I have found some of the example for assigning private key into a variable like below,
private const string PrivateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"+ "MIICWwIBAAKBgQDgAmkirAgwCst/Sp4/s/H6H/qt0eJx1o2bhNiPhm19HWOdI3xN\r\n"+ "IggoDEZHlZYkuTWAhqjWN+PN8DeZfbhCsHwkv3sS5DW1vN8eRVP78ak5ZCg5Z++0\r\n"+ "fHmOK92W1yvDNtiRlZ71XQuqxWiFDwh37Nl8tFcfV+UQbNJev6DRPhf51wIDAQAB\r\n"+ "AoGASj5iTByKZindwmWfx2tDguwAcIXEsIg0zNudzwv10+besiElvIbP/z36ORWJ\r\n"+ "+sfrxJpc8Qr7FLFOLDAv1uKZchG+r26FyqLMLJjAgy5Ks4/BuDB9e+CIAdGXX25m\r\n"+ "rDzjKRl/p7ojMSxq6sWDwxXX4Ypj3v+L1hLWzX4C6bobsaECQQD1j6EFQWi250TP\r\n"+ "mObqniYvCOl+zHCSNmd9cELkP69H4/Rwx01Oew+brHeXlBMeWONdsuUUHlV/3bPs\r\n"+ "SFfE1VjHAkEA6Yg9zHWvEAwayiO9uGvfr64KB7DC+lnw1i2sIhZ8zxT6Vqb3b9iX\r\n"+ "HQE7soTZ/GuamKkvUpTMUEO8CPpnMY/mcQJAeo692cakgaz5bfctQOm/uvfiubNF\r\n"+ "d+QJUNTnvc1/KQ0/oc4G6mWHC7ZPVerEg//vMoOny5u8Jn47X3FXxNiKXwJAbzLG\r\n"+ "amLnFvcMko/uOLB09IwkjoDmdpr5CKL6wch/aYONqFEcpQ829UKvEFQeEAmUtXhp\r\n"+ "5iKgHuAB2yyQkpL4oQJAf3LGn5PgAqdM+q4KUZtHlRSIruFzgwhMjhuQfKs1Hw1W\r\n"+ "D80YIpCkhS7dNatVLWIWisD3ll/hUIFZXsLgvNlHPw==\r\n"+ "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n";

I have used KeyGenerator.exe file to generate public and private key. It generated 2 XML file one is public and other is private. Now these files are having XML nodes like below,
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>s9vdfnfgyMbqIL31eQX35eA/pdM2uwm8MSxv36t0irpuMYuObR210kWCFCu/n766jZ3c5LNtmeRfo5AA8UDMafJ6EtZQnUx76rEeMJobDRgWrUdTb9x5EEmcL0um/vijOjI5Lk8PVqjg5tCJ19E8A8oK5dkc2MPDq15ksGnT40b9/TMocSSedNcCc4JTfCBWv4KXAm7s+Gty/y47LfOTwu2MEEECSYfPQZ3CKhkxXX0SwgDYMJW0ou1yOdeQPehIkxSjt9Ynd20zw2AyjsmMvb0T635dJlSLzmVTV5HYo9Aghgq7lY1NH+BrMJ+keMhzQC+wUwa+wv2x/mCIzX2y+Q==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>y9MxLWJ4URJUWLwwJC/P08rxeP0KZDJ5JD+0kCDDFRqlMI41jF5VVllbxokZaqOpQaMIFvPMwHR3etqT9n90ZYZKORC6TGvdaHJ/ewWpCtMrLusG5ypCHXfPiLL425yTaBaDSbbnHV3ooPL4GWX1n9+GAr1EsoGodNYyBzEnb1M=</P><Q>4eYnmYJtSpyv3995eQk0uIAV4Q8ijHbBtUp8iK2k92pIyascnMdpglbNSGwPF+siwbtN/4VvZZXjHbWMe2KbhqcR6wlH+nxtyQWzBRKCEsG+JTmS4TBKwpKC5sFv3+C17CCB/L2zvGrR0vW5JErQ0KmWzbPqL20A4ViKc+QvZwM=</Q><DP>qbd+2VWG7aqfhQud4mPVX3s6ug2pG2lTqbVJ+kDtb6MyLU4clHbwA+iAHL6H5V3FT5wa3lG/Cflwi2F5luTl3KuHHiEpnvyp7ZB5ScyaxyKycGzO4Kk1SCg9LIwp32Nu8lrckwKzSqapT2tA3pUhgy+x/JHwo9qGlFLOcWKifXU=</DP><DQ>gDQowTx+XlvyjLG9tO1+mD9JK4N1bhZv9T2i08cI2sndKWcNRAUAYlJ1CucY4dA215A/wgaupA6e6NuCMPxTm+Xxi1ynFwfLHs03Pme0noSKL4IvU9Iee7K+y8t4fKyBUtNYMmJPQV22W23Nd0VmoSW+SlwTSnsohrvDR+Z26JU=</DQ><InverseQ>PO6hut+3R4JqDVgWxZ6uia+1NmH0ywXwr/wuxzj9/IOSD1nJOsBWSOqge6qXe9IBbTdpS0RAdV7g96O/DgiD+nhZoC4eOx2GNehnhaGWzHa+jPGP57Gy1v7IF7uKOaSbnAarEWq8i/dQxwhyKnVQ6lMaLGrT5BxDalTJKof80Nc=</InverseQ><D>C9QLzwNnPw0F3L1hZWIlGXMT/H3VfZt4SuuXN+h4s57rHEsHRNnNWVTE5zqxUXojnqihHFFIhfRk7cbMqREP4G/X42FAz/d1tsuLJrsbyFKrOx4TuKmRNKcCpIGfK+mCIpOm+wqsAZD9qXBRgGX8QmuJJ/CNWxwUxDJjAM8U5j9qteuouqZyMjxYld9krSkouVxZeACC7VpO3UjAd/QfIs6p8q6mjRnsTUiVeIfTlzhBwNY8AyjaneIaenTWhEfIW9A0ZFbIz+D2sacBs5dbzB2Q4S2rM3OgMjbj0c6kYiI/UXsUZuRK/ZI7nvlovQKU1yFgo+OkXDpoB1HMrS2xGQ==</D>
</RSAKeyValue>

So, my question is how to assign this private key XML values into a c sharp variable like example above.

Here is the code may help you:

make a RSA key help class:

public class RSAKeyHelper
{
    public static RSACryptoServiceProvider LoadPrivateKeyFromXml(string xmlString)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(xmlString);
        return rsa;
    }

    public static string GetPrivateKeyXml(string filePath)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(filePath);
        return xmlDoc.OuterXml;
    }
}


use it in your main class:

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string privateKeyFilePath = "path_to_your_private_key.xml";
        string privateKeyXml = RSAKeyHelper.GetPrivateKeyXml(privateKeyFilePath);
        
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = RSAKeyHelper.LoadPrivateKeyFromXml(privateKeyXml);
        
        // You can now use rsaProvider to encrypt, decrypt, sign, etc.
        
        Console.WriteLine("Private key loaded successfully.");
    }
}


rsaProvider needs a using. Also what's the point of XmlDocument is it just to veify that it's valid XML, because it's not doing anything else?

@Charlieface Hi Charlie , yes for efficiency we should use using in order to dispose the object. With xml doc at first we can load xml file stream , by returning outerXml the object will be returned and then in Load privatekey that object will be get used.

So why do you need that, why not just File.ReadAllText

First of all, I would like to mention that RSA private keys have the following properties: modulus, exponnet, p, q, dp, dq, inverseq, d. So we also need to assign them to the C# variables separately.
 string privateKeyXml = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\v-qyou\\Desktop\\PrivateKey.xml");
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);
    RSAParameters privateKeyParams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
    string modulus = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.Modulus);
    string exponent= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.Exponent);
    string p = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.P);
    string q = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.Q);
    string dp= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.DP);
    string dq= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.DQ);
    string inverseq= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.InverseQ);
    string d= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.D);
    }




Got it. but I need a private key as string to process it further like mentioned in the question.
private const string PrivateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n"+ "MIICWwIBAAK.........\r\n"+ "\r\n"+ "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n";

In fact, the data has been converted into strings. The format of the data you want can be done directly through string concatenation.

Simple string concatenation:
string privateKeyXml = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\v-qyou\\Desktop\\PrivateKey.xml");
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);

    RSAParameters privateKeyParams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
    string modulus = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.Modulus);
    string exponent= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.Exponent);
    string p = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.P);
    string q = Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.Q);
    string dp= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.DP);
    string dq= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.DQ);
    string inverseq= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.InverseQ);
    string d= Convert.ToBase64String(privateKeyParams.D);
   
    string str = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n" + modulus.Substring(0, 64) +
        "\r\n" + modulus.Substring(64, 64) + "\r\n" +
        modulus.Substring(128, 64) + "\r\n" +
        modulus.Substring(192, 64) + "\r\n" +
        modulus.Substring(256, 64) + "\r\n" +
        modulus.Substring(320, 24) + exponent + p.Substring(0, 36) + "\r\n" +
        p.Substring(36, 64) + "\r\n" +
    p.Substring(100, 64) + "\r\n" +
    p.Substring(164, 8) + q.Substring(0, 56) + "\r\n" +
    q.Substring(56, 64) + "\r\n" +
    q.Substring(120, 52) + dq.Substring(0, 12) + "\r\n" +
    dq.Substring(12, 64) + "\r\n" +
    dq.Substring(76, 64) + "\r\n" +
    dq.Substring(140, 32) + dp.Substring(0, 32) + "\r\n" +
    dp.Substring(32, 64) + "\r\n" +
     dp.Substring(96, 64) + "\r\n" +
     dp.Substring(160, 12) + inverseq.Substring(0, 52) + "\r\n" +
     inverseq.Substring(52, 64) + "\r\n" +
     inverseq.Substring(116, 56) + d.Substring(0, 8) + "\r\n" +
     d.Substring(8, 64) + "\r\n" +
     d.Substring(72, 64) + "\r\n" +
     d.Substring(136, 64) + "\r\n" +
      d.Substring(200, 64) + "\r\n" +
       d.Substring(264, 64) + "\r\n" +
        d.Substring(328, 16) + "\r\n"+ "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n";

   


